# CPU acronyms - MVB

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5, acronym

I was looking through the specifications for a notebook and came across an acronym I had not seen before:

[image: Screenshot]

Some Google foo has established that its apparently a big deal if you're a vet, but I cant find anything related to processors. What does it stand for / what does it do?

Comment: Probably just a typo, the CPU has a 3MB level 3 cache which would often be mentioned when outlining its specifications. The V and B keys are next to each other after all.

Comment: looks about right. Between that and what the ARK says, @JamesP might have an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's almost certainly just a typo and is meant to say `3 MB` to refer to the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) size which is something that would frequently be mentioned when listing a laptop's specification.

Checking the Intel [product page for the i5-7200U](https://ark.intel.com/products/95443/Intel-Core-i5-7200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) it does indeed list the cache size as 3 MB but sites like [NotebookCheck](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i5-7200U-Notebook-Processor.172250.0.html) will often give more detailed information and you can see that there are actually three separate cache 'levels' not just one.

The typo theory would be further supported by the fact that the <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> keys are adjacent to each other on most keyboards.